# Error on the query string SQL

Tags: c#, mysql

Im getting the following error:

> "A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll Additional information: Incorrect syntax
>   near ')'. If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be
>   safely continued."

Is this syntax? i really cant figure this out, can anyone tell what i am doing wrong?

```
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("A Atualizar dados...");
        bool check = true;
        do
        {
            string connectionString = @"Data Source=.\wintouch;Initial Catalog=bbl;User ID=sa;Password=Pa$$w0rd";
            string queryString = string.Empty;
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                queryString = "UPDATE  wgcdoccab SET merc1 = merc1/2 WHERE numdoc = (SELECT MAX(numdoc) FROM WGCDOCCAB WHERE serie ='1' and tipodoc ='FSS' and contribuinte ='999999990' and  datadoc = CONVERT(varchar(10),(dateadd(dd, -1, getdate())), 120))";
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connection.Close();
            }
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();

                queryString = "SELECT max(numdoc) FROM wgcdoccab WHERE serie ='1' and tipodoc ='FSS' and contribuinte ='999999990' and datadoc = CONVERT(varchar(10),(dateadd(dd, -1, getdate())), 120))";
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection))
                using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (reader.HasRows)
                    {

                        check = true;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        check = false;
                        MessageBox.Show("Dados atualizados com sucesso");
                    }
                    command.Connection.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        while (check);
```

Comment: well, which of the queries is throwing that error? probably both, since you have too many `)` at the end of them...

Comment: Start to run your queries part by part. Start small parts and go bigger ones. I'm sure you will find your extra/unnecessary `(` or `)` in your code.

Comment: Visual Studio is highlighting the SELECT query. I'm not sure, the code seem to be right.

Comment: why do you have a boatload of `)` next to getdate. How about using curdate() or something that exists ? count your opening and closing `(` `)`

Comment: Looks like you have an extra ')' at the end of the select statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your SQL Statements.  This line has too many parentheses:

```
queryString = "SELECT max(numdoc) FROM wgcdoccab WHERE serie ='1' and tipodoc ='FSS' and contribuinte ='999999990' and datadoc = CONVERT(varchar(10),(dateadd(dd, -1, getdate())), 120))";
```

Comment: Yes that was the problem, i ended up checking the lines and parentheses one by one. But still thank you for the answer!